# Does anybody knows why I'm stuck with an infinity loading compiling?

Tags: latex, tikz

I have an infinity loading compiling my LaTeX script... I don't know why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%Colonnes:
\usepackage{multicol}
%Marges:
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
%maths:
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%tikzpicture:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%pgfplots:
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\title{Analyse}
\author{Philippe B}
\date{Juin 2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Exercice}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]                                                                 %   changer la taille du document
        \draw[ultra thin, black!10,->] (-5,-5)grid(5,5);                                            %   dimension et espacement de la grille
        \draw[line width=0.5pt, black,->] (-5,0)--(5,0)node[right]{$x$};                            %   Axe x
        \draw[line width=0.5pt, black,->] (0,-5)--(0,5)node[above]{$y$};                            %   Axe y
        \foreach \x in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}                                                        %   Graduation x
        { \draw (\x,0.05cm)-- (\x,-0.05cm) node[below] {\scriptsize $\x\strut$}; }                  %   ------------
        \foreach \y in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}                                                        %   Graduation y
        { \draw (0.05cm,\y)-- (-0.05cm,\y) node[left] {\scriptsize $\y\strut$}; }                   %   ------------
        \clip(-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);                                                                 %   Encadrement de la fonction
        \draw   [
                very thin,
                smooth,
                samples=100,
                blue!50,
                domain=-5:5
                ]
                
                plot(\x,{\x*\x-3*\x-1});
                
        \node at(-4.5,4.5){\footnotesize \color{blue!50}$f(x)$};
                
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
        \draw   [
                ultra thin,
                black!10,
                ] 
                (-5,-5)grid(5,5);
        \draw   [
                line width=0.5pt,
                black,
                ] 
                (-5,0)--(5,0)node[right]{$x$}
        \draw   [
                line width=0.5pt,
                black,
                ] 
                (0,-5)--(0,5)node[above]{$y$};
        \foreach \x in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
        { \draw (\x,0.05cm)-- (\x,-0.05cm) node[below] {\scriptsize $\x\strut$}; }
        \foreach \y in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
        { \draw (0.05cm,\y)-- (-0.05cm,\y) node[left] {\scriptsize $\y\strut$}; }
        \clip(-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
        \node at(-4.5,4.5){\footnotesize \color{blue!50}$g(x)$};
        \draw   [
                very thin,
                color=blue!50,
                smooth,
                samples=100,
                domain=-5:5
                ] 
                
                plot(\x,{sqrt(((\x)^(2)+18)/((\x)^(2)+1))});
                
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing semicolon in l. 69:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%Colonnes:
\usepackage{multicol}
%Marges:
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}
%maths:
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%tikzpicture:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%pgfplots:
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\title{Analyse}
\author{Philippe B}
\date{Juin 2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Exercice}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]                                                                 %   changer la taille du document
        \draw[ultra thin, black!10,->] (-5,-5)grid(5,5);                                            %   dimension et espacement de la grille
        \draw[line width=0.5pt, black,->] (-5,0)--(5,0)node[right]{$x$};                            %   Axe x
        \draw[line width=0.5pt, black,->] (0,-5)--(0,5)node[above]{$y$};                            %   Axe y
        \foreach \x in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}                                                        %   Graduation x
        { \draw (\x,0.05cm)-- (\x,-0.05cm) node[below] {\scriptsize $\x\strut$}; }                  %   ------------
        \foreach \y in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}                                                        %   Graduation y
        { \draw (0.05cm,\y)-- (-0.05cm,\y) node[left] {\scriptsize $\y\strut$}; }                   %   ------------
        \clip(-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);                                                                 %   Encadrement de la fonction
        \draw   [
                very thin,
                smooth,
                samples=100,
                blue!50,
                domain=-5:5
                ]
                
                plot(\x,{\x*\x-3*\x-1});
                
        \node at(-4.5,4.5){\footnotesize \color{blue!50}$f(x)$};
%                
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
        \draw   [
                ultra thin,
                black!10,
                ] 
                (-5,-5)grid(5,5);
        \draw   [
                line width=0.5pt,
                black,
                ] 
                (-5,0)--(5,0)node[right]{$x$};
        \draw   [
                line width=0.5pt,
                black,
                ] 
                (0,-5)--(0,5)node[above]{$y$};
        \foreach \x in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
        { \draw (\x,0.05cm)-- (\x,-0.05cm) node[below] {\scriptsize $\x\strut$}; }
        \foreach \y in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
        { \draw (0.05cm,\y)-- (-0.05cm,\y) node[left] {\scriptsize $\y\strut$}; }
        \clip(-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
        \node at(-4.5,4.5){\footnotesize \color{blue!50}$g(x)$};
        \draw   [
                very thin,
                color=blue!50,
                smooth,
                samples=100,
                domain=-5:5
                ] 
                
                plot(\x,{sqrt(((\x)^(2)+18)/((\x)^(2)+1))});
                
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A BIG BIG thanks to you !

Comment: @PhJohn You're welcome! In case you find yourself again in a similar situation, try to comment the whole tikzpicture and then add back in one line after the other. This way you can spot which line is the problem.